# How to return another component inside condition from stateless component

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, jsx, react-component

This stateless component is being render inside a class component render method. This stateless component then will return null or another class component based on the condition but it gives me an error.

```
const AdminTools = () => { 
        const userID = auth.currentUser;
        let userRef = firebase.database().ref("users");
        if(userID){
            userRef.child(userID.uid).once('child_added', snap => {
                if(snap.val().role == 'Admin'){
                    return <AdminPanel/>
                        } else {
                      return null     
                        }
            });
        }
    }
```

Error:

> Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.

How do i return something as a result from the condition?
i tried declaring variable like this but same error.

```
const AdminTools = () => { 
        let res;
        const userID = auth.currentUser;
        let userRef = firebase.database().ref("users");
        if(userID){
            userRef.child(userID.uid).once('child_added', snap => {
                if(snap.val().role == 'Admin'){
                    res =  <AdminPanel/>
                        } else {
                    res = null     
                        }
            });
        }
           return res;
    }
```

Comment: I don't get what you're trying to do here, is `AdminTools` some sort of recursive component?

Comment: it's a stateless component

Comment: You actually can't have stateless component that runs some async effect and then rerenders on its own. Because loaded/unloaded is **state**.

Comment: What's my best chance of getting this done?

Comment: @JuanDelaCruz You could create a stateful component that does loading on `componentDidMount` and renders null initially and stateless presentational component once data has been loaded. As described in Philippe Leefsma's answer

Answer (score 0):

If no userId is found then nothing will be returned from the render, you need to return null if not userId is present like

```
const AdminTools = () => { 
    const userID = auth.currentUser;
    let userRef = firebase.database().ref("users");
    if(userID){
        userRef.child(userID.uid).once('child_added', snap => {
            if(snap.val().role == 'Admin'){
                return <AdminTools/>
            } else {
                  return null     
            }
        });
    }
    return null;   // return null here
}
```

Comment: Why will it immediately return, it will do so only if userId is not found, think of it as an else condition to if(userID)

Comment: The userid is not immediately available i think

Comment: In that case you need to use async-await or a promise

Answer (score 0):

A render method cannot be asynchronous, the `once` method takes a callback as second argument. Returning something from a callback will not return a value from the calling method, unless you are using async or promise as mentioned in the comments.

What you should do is in `componentDidMount`, invoke the   `userRef.child(userID.uid).once` and based on the return value, use `setState` in your component to trigger a re-render which will return either the admin panel or null/false.

If you want to keep your component stateless then you cannot run that logic inside, a stateless component will take props as input and always render the same output. You can move the asynchronous call to the parent or implement that logic somewhere else, in an action handler for example, this depends which flux implementation you are using.